# Query to get no of non matching rows count for two tables using Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have Two Tables.

```html
Table1 :-

Col1

AAA

BBB

CCC

Table2 :-

Col1

AAA

BBB

ZZZ
```

I want to get output :- `2`
in above two tables contains 2 matching rows and two non maching rows. How to write Sql query to get count for non matching rows.

Comment: Why did you tag Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **number of non-matching rows**, one simple way of doing it would be as shown below. We get the number of rows in `Table1` that are not present in `Table2`, we get the number of rows in `Table2` not in `Table1`, and we add both. `UNION ALL` combines the results of both queries (we use this instead of `UNION` because `UNION` discards duplicates).

```
SELECT SUM(NonMatchingRows) AS TotalNonMatchingRows 
FROM ( 
  -- Rows from Table1 that don't have a match in Table2 
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS NonMatchingRows 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE Col1 NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM Table2 ) 
  UNION ALL 
  -- Rows from Table2 that don't have a match in Table1 
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS NonMatchingRows 
  FROM Table2 
  WHERE Col1 NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM Table1 ) 
) AS X
```

To get the number of *matching* rows, you'd run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MatchingRows 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
  ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
```

This inner join returns only the rows that have the same values for `Col1` in both tables. Note that in case one single row in `Table 1` matches 2 rows in `Table 2`, this query will return 2.